# dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore: Invalid item argument in dijit.tree

Tags: dojo, dijit.tree

While working with dojo toolkit and the `djit.tree` widget, I received the the following error:

```
dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore: Invalid item argument
```

in my javascript function which loads data in json format from my php server and displays it in a `dijit.tree` using a `ItemFileWriteStore`   and a `ForestStoreModel`. My json data is the following:

```
{
    "identifier": "id",
    "label": "name",
    "items": [{
        "type": "parent",
        "name": "Adresse des Finanzamts",
        "id": "1020right00",
        "children": [{
            "type": "Leaf",
            "name": "Relationship type: 1:1",
            "id": "Adresse des Finanzamts1:1"
        }, {
            "type": "parent",
            "name": "Left",
            "id": "Adresse des Finanzamts010",
            "children": [{
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Table name: Finanzamtdaten",
                "id": "1014left23432"
            }, {
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Field name: fkFinanzamtAdresse:INTEGER",
                "id": "1018lef423t"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "parent",
            "name": "Right",
            "id": "Adresse des Finanzamts111",
            "children": [{
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Table name: Adresse",
                "id": "105right234"
            }, {
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Field name: adresseId:INTEGER",
                "id": "106right2223"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "type": "parent",
        "name": "Adresse des Mitarbeiters",
        "id": "1013right00",
        "children": [{
            "type": "Leaf",
            "name": "Relationship type: 1:1",
            "id": "Adresse des Mitarbeiters1:1"
        }, {
            "type": "parent",
            "name": "Left",
            "id": "Adresse des Mitarbeiters010",
            "children": [{
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Table name: Mitarbeiter",
                "id": "100left23432"
            }, {
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Field name: fkAdresse:INTEGER",
                "id": "1012lef423t"
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "parent",
            "name": "Right",
            "id": "Adresse des Mitarbeiters111",
            "children": [{
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Table name: Adresse",
                "id": "105right234"
            }, {
                "type": "Leaf",
                "name": "Field name: adresseId:INTEGER",
                "id": "106right2223"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

The code is formatted on server side using `json_encode()`.

```
 var treeObject = dijit.byId("relationStructure");
            treeObject.model.store.clearOnClose = true;
            treeObject.model.store.close();
            var newStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                data: data
            });

            treeObject.model.store = newStore;
            treeObject.model.query = {"type": "parent"};
            treeObject.rootId = "root";
            treeObject.rootLabel = "Table content";
            treeObject.childrenAttrs = ["children"];
            treeObject.showRoot = false;

            treeObject.refreshModel();
```

Now json data:

```
  {"identifier":"id","label":"name","items":[{"type":"parent","name":"Finanzamtdaten des Mitarbeiters","id":"1022right000","children":[{"type":"Leaf","name":"Relationship type: 1:1","id":"Finanzamtdaten des Mitarbeiters1:1"},{"type":"parent","name":"Left","id":"Finanzamtdaten des Mitarbeiters0100","children":[{"type":"Leaf","name":"Table name: Mitarbeiter","id":"100left234320"},{"type":"Leaf","name":"Field name: fkFinanzamtdaten:INTEGER","id":"1019lef423t0"}]},{"type":"parent","name":"Right","id":"Finanzamtdaten des Mitarbeiters1110","children":[{"type":"Leaf","name":"Table name: Finanzamtdaten","id":"1014right2340"},{"type":"Leaf","name":"Field name: finanzamtdatenId:INTEGER","id":"1015right22230"}]}]},{"type":"parent","name":"Adresse des Mitarbeiters","id":"1013right001","children":[{"type":"Leaf","name":"Relationship type: 1:1","id":"Adresse des Mitarbeiters1:1"},{"type":"parent","name":"Left","id":"Adresse des Mitarbeiters0101","children":[{"type":"Leaf","name":"Table name: Mitarbeiter","id":"100left234321"},{"type":"Leaf","name":"Field name: fkAdresse:INTEGER","id":"1012lef423t1"}]},{"type":"parent","name":"Right","id":"Adresse des Mitarbeiters1111","children":[{"type":"Leaf","name":"Table name: Adresse","id":"105right2341"},{"type":"Leaf","name":"Field name: adresseId:INTEGER","id":"106right22231"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: please show me the whole intaciation of the store

Comment: added the function code, please note, that a similar function is used for another dijit.tree on my website and it is working fine. Also it has been working previously, but for this json data not. The method refreshModel() is added using dojo extending functionality. It refresh the tree and thats all.

Comment: did you also parse the json before?

Comment: yes and the code work already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an id collision with your data.  There are two items with the same id of `105right234` and `106right2223`.

```
"dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore:  The json data provided by the creation arguments 
is malformed.  Items within the list have identifier: [id].  
Value collided: [105right234]"
```

If you want the same item to appear twice in the structure, then you need to look at how the `_reference` structure is used.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#input-data-format

---

Your second set of data loads fine into the store.

The following code is not good practice for Dojo widgets.

```
treeObject.model.store = newStore;
treeObject.model.query = {"type": "parent"};
treeObject.rootId = "root";
treeObject.rootLabel = "Table content";
treeObject.childrenAttrs = ["children"];
treeObject.showRoot = false;
```

Dojo uses the convention of myWidget.set('model', new model);  This allows for custom setter logic.  See this link for more.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#custom-setters-getters

I created another fiddle that uses your data and creates a tree.

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/5Yjx9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/4r4tf/ shows the creation of the store and the error that I posted in my answer.

Comment: sorry, but I failed to added the code to your testing application at jsfiddle.net

Comment: Added a second fiddle to address the widget now that the data is ok.

Comment: Because setting properties directly after a widget is instantiated will not run the custom setter code.

Comment: I am new to dojo, so what do you mean with. The dijit.tree is created after loading the page with emtpty datastore, there only standts "No relations". After user interaction, the new datastore is loaded using dojo.xhrPost and the function above in the description.

Comment: curious, I tested my code this morning and it work fine (it tested it more than 10 times to be sure with different json data from my database)